# How to check with Selenium redirection to external protocol?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, selenium, firefox-addon

I want to use Selenium to check that clicking a specific button redirects to a specific URL with external protocol (`myApp:\\`).

The problem is that the redirect is not by `"href"` attribute, but it triggers JavaScript `onClick` call.

How can I use Selenium to assert that redirect?

I have tried:

1. Right clicking and opening a new tab - it doesn't trigger the JavaScript.
2. Clicking the button itself does nothing (as it's an external protocol).
3. I thought writing a chrome extension that shows the requested URL when called. My extension will be registered to handle the external protocol.

However Chrome extension can handle only `web+myApp`, which I cannot change.

Comment: Could you provide us with a specific reproducable example? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your js redirect function and are you doing selenium in java?

Comment: Have you tried the window.unload event?

Comment: Which binding for Selenium are you using?  Are you using the legacy driver or are you using a WebDriver binding in an environment such as Java, NodeJS, or Ruby?

Comment: @Mark WebDriver  to chromeDriver, java